# Evaluate without L'Hopital: $\lim_{x \to 3} (x-3)\csc\pi x $

Tags: trigonometry, limits-without-lhopital

I'm supposed to evaluate this limit without using L'Hopital's rule.

> $$\lim_{x \to 3} (x-3)\csc\pi x $$

I find the indeterminate form of $0$ or $\frac{0}{0}$. The latter tells me that L'Hopital's is an option, but since we haven't seen derivatives yet I'm not allowed to used it.

Previously I already tried swapping the $\csc\pi x$ for $\frac{1}{\sin\pi x}$ but when doing this I can't seem to get rid of the sinus. I also believe that since the limit goes to $3$ and not to $0$, the $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin ax}{ax} = 1$ rule is not an option either.

I tried making the $\sin(\frac{\pi}{2})$ so that $=1$, but without any success. Can anyone give me a hint? I don't need a full solution as I want to try and find it myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Edited because I just realised you don't want a full solution)

**Hint**: $\sin(x) = -\sin(x + 3\pi)$. Try a substitution such that the limit you mentioned is an option!

Comment: Sorry, I'm still having some trouble. By "such that the limit you mentioned is an option" do you mean $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin ax}{ax} = 1$ ? Because i thought this was only viable when the limit goes to 0.

Comment: Yes, it is indeed. But now take the substitution $y = x-3$, in which case $\lim_{x \to 3}$ is the same as $\lim_{y \to 0}$.

Comment: Typo: $\sin(x\color{red}-3\pi)$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust $+3\pi$ and $-3\pi$ have a difference that is a multiple of $2\pi$, so it's not a typo. And I wanted it to have $+3\pi$ in there because that's what you obtain once you substitute.

Comment: The limit is that of $-(x-3)/\sin(\pi x-\pi 3)=-y/\sin(\pi y)$. It would make no sense to use a $+$.

Comment: Perhaps my use of $x$ in my hint is confusing. My idea was to substitute $\sin(\pi x) = \sin(\pi(y+3)) = \sin(\pi y + 3\pi)$, in which case it does make sense.

Answer (score 2):

By a change of variable,

$$\lim_{x\to3}\frac{x-3}{\sin\pi x}=\lim_{y\to0}\frac{y}{\sin(\pi y+3\pi)}=-\frac1\pi\lim_{y\to0}\frac{\pi y}{\sin(\pi y)}.$$

Comment: May I ask how you were able to work away the $3\pi $ inside the sine?

Comment: @TheAlPaca02: no, this is trivial.